# Number of steps required to sort the array using permutation

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, permutation

Given a permutation array P (1-based indexing), find the total number of steps required to sort the same array using the permutation array.

Constraints:

n = arr.length

2<=n<=10^5

Example:
Say P =[2,5,4,3,1]

Copy the array from P to arr
arr = [2,5,4,3,1]
step1 -> arr = [5,1,3,4,2] {Here the elements are arranged according to the permutation array, (i.e, permutation array P is considered here as index array to arrange elements)
Here, 2nd element (5) comes 1st place because in P, 2 is at 1st position
5th element (1) comes 2nd place because in P, 5 is at 2nd position and so on...}

step2 -> arr = [1,2,4,3,5]

step3 -> arr = [2,5,4,3,1]

step4 -> arr = [5,1,4,3,2]

step5 -> arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

Hence, total number of steps required = 5

Expecting O(n) algorithm according to given constraints.

Thank you.

Comment: _"find the total number of steps"_. Did you mean _minimum_ number of steps? Because "total" seems arbitrary in this case

Comment: Based on the question title I expected something about [bogosort](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort).

Answer (score 0):

A permutation is composed of cycles of various lengths (from 1 to N).

Choose some position in the permutation array and lookup the index at that location. Then lookup the index at the new location, and so on. After a while you will come back to the initial position. At the same time as you follow the indexes, you can move the elements in the main array.

To make sure to follow all cycles, use a running index to the permutation array; every time you visit a position, mark it as visited; after you have finished a cycle, advance the index to the next unmarked position.

Using this procedure, you will mark all N indexes and move all array elements at most once, for a total workload O(N).